# How to align an image at the bottom of li element?

Tags: html, css

How to align an image at the bottom of li element. In my case I need the smile align with the bottom edge of the square.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jvgrz/

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"></li>
</ul>


li {
    position: relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid red;

}
```

Comment: Why does the `li` have relative position? What role does the placeholder text in the other two elements play? It's trivially easy to make the image go at the bottom, but it's much harder to do so without messing up the other things you might want to do and are not telling.

Comment: where exactly at the bottom do you want this smiley face?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the image have an absolute position with css.... like this.

```
li img { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set absolute position to your img tag to achieve it.

Here is [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jvgrz/5/)

In CSS add this img clause

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its some kind of botton edge then you might use it as:

```
img {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
```

As to make sure that the image is somewhere at the edge not in the center. If maybe you want in center. Then remove right:0px;
However you can use this:

```
img {
 align: center|top|left|right;
 }
```

As this is supported by all major browsers!